# Не понимаю как спарсить все статьи. POST запрос не работает

Tags: php, парсер, curl, parse

Использую PHP. Пытаюсь через CURL получить страницу (страницу получаю). Но на странице отображается только 34 новости, и все следующие подгружаются с помощью AJAX через POST запрос, при нажатии кнопки. Пытаюсь получить данные с помощью CURL используя данные для пост запроса, но получаю пустую страницу. Что я делаю не так, и как в подобных ситуация можно получить ссылки на енное количество новостей? Я пока только учусь парсить, заказ не коммерческий, поэтому не пинайте сильно. Спасибо.

  P.S. Я пробовал пост запросы отправлять и строкой, и ассоциативным массивом, на страницу getPosts.php и на простую страницу новостей.
Сам код:

```
function request($url,$postdata = null,$cookie = 'cookiefile.txt' ){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    if($postdata){
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    }
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;

}

file_put_contents('cookiefile.txt', '');

$post = ['action' => 'getPostsByCategory','category'=>'1','offset'=>'4','postperpage'=>'60'];
$html = request('https://forklog.com/wp-content/themes/forklogv2/ajax/getPosts.php',$post);
var_dump($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Поигрался с запросом, опытным путем выяснил, что пустой ответ приходит в случае если не передавать заголовок

```
 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```

Исходный запрос был:

```
await fetch("https://forklog.com/wp-content/themes/forklogv2/ajax/getPosts.php", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic ....==",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    "referrer": "https://forklog.com/news/",
    "body": "action=getPostsByCategory&category=1&offset=34&postperpage=34",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors"
});
```

Попробуйте добавить:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8']);
```

Comment: Добавил эту строку, всё равно пустоту возвращает.

Comment: Можно попробовать остальные заголовки из исходного запроса добавить, или еще referrer попробовать установить curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https ://forklog.com/news/');